# Is there a safe balace board that is more challenging than a Wobble board?

Tags: balance

Is there a Wobble board which is significantly more challenging than the common ones?

Is there a safer type of a Rola Bola/Indoboard (and how safe is it?)

Or maybe something in between, challenging though not dangerous even for spotter-free practice?

Answer (score 1):

Define safe.  None of this is perfectly safe, and I don't think that there's any clear line where it's "safe" on one side and "not safe" on the other.

There are more challenging balance boards (put a plank on a ball, put a plank on a tapered roller, put a shorter plank on a roller, juggle while on the plank & roller).  I've fallen off of all of these, and nothing was injured besides my pride.

But only you get to decide what's safe enough for you.

Good luck!